# PySimpleGUI: How do I convert a value from string to float using

Tags: pysimplegui

I have a short PySimpleGUI program to test FocusOut. Jason Yang provided the code which works exactly as I want it to. However, a new problem has surfaced and I am therefore posting it as a new question.
In the code below, if one fails to enter and amount in say the '*FUELQUANT*' field an error is raised and a popup generated. However, if you enter a value, say 13.5 I want it to reflect in the Inbox as 13.50. To do so I want to read the value in the field then format it to 2 decimal places and return it via .update to the Inbox.
My problem is that as soon as I put in the formatting code line(s), then if there is no value in the Inbox (i.e when it should cause the popup to activate), I get an error: "could not convert string to float: ' ' "  Is there a way around this? I have tried everything that I could find to try to solve the problem but nothing seems to work.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
import sqlite3
from datetime import date
import time

TodayDt=date.today()
print("Today's date is " + str(TodayDt))


def popup(*args, elem=None):
    for element in elements:
        element.unbind('<FocusOut>')
    window.refresh()                        # Make unbind effect
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('\n'.join(args))],
        [sg.Button('OK')],
    ]
    sg.Window('Popup', layout).read(close=True)
    if elem:
        elem.set_focus()
        window.refresh()                    # Make set_focus effect
    for element in elements:
        element.bind('<FocusOut>','+FOCUS OUT')

layout=[
[sg.T("Today's date is:"),sg.InputText(TodayDt, size=(10, 10), key='_TODAYCAL_')],
[sg.T("Select new transaction date:"),sg.CalendarButton('Calendar',  target='-IN4-', key='_DATE_',format='%Y-%m-%d'),sg.In(key='-IN4-', size=(10,1))],
[sg.T("Fuel quantity (in litres):"),sg.In(key="_FUELQUANT_",size=(10,1),enable_events=True),sg.T("Fuel amount N$:"),sg.In(key="_FUELAMNT_", size=(10,1),enable_events=True)],
[sg.T("Oil quantity (in millilitres:"),sg.In(key="_OILQUANT_",size=(10,1)),sg.T("Oil amount N$:"),sg.In(key="_OILAMNT_",size=(10,1))],
]
window = sg.Window('My Vehicle Logbook', layout, finalize=True)
keys = ('_FUELQUANT_','_FUELAMNT_')
elements = [window[key] for key in keys]
for element in elements:
    element.bind('<FocusOut>','+FOCUS OUT')

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':     # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break

    elif event.endswith("+FOCUS OUT"):

        print(event)
        key = event.split('+')[0]

        amount=values[key]
        print(str(amount))
        
        #amount="{: .2f}".format(float(amount))
        # window.find_element(key).update(amount)
        print(amount)
        if values[key] == '':
            popup("Warning", f"Blank entry in {key} is not acceptable !", elem=window[key])

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is about the programming logic.

Demo code for it

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def popup(*args, elem=None):
    for element in elements:
        element.unbind('<FocusOut>')
    window.refresh()                        # Make unbind effect
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('\n'.join(args))],
        [sg.Button('OK')],
    ]
    sg.Window('Popup', layout).read(close=True)
    if elem:
        elem.set_focus()
        window.refresh()                    # Make set_focus effect
    for element in elements:
        element.bind('<FocusOut>','+FOCUS OUT')

layout=[[sg.Input(key=f'-IN{i}-')] for i in range(5)]

window = sg.Window('My Vehicle Logbook', layout, finalize=True)
keys = ('-IN1-', '-IN2-')
elements = [window[key] for key in keys]
for element in elements:
    element.bind('<FocusOut>','+FOCUS OUT')

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':     # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    elif event.endswith("+FOCUS OUT"):
        key = event.split('+')[0]
        try:
            number = float(values[key])
            string = f'{number:.2f}'
            window[key].update(string)
        except ValueError:
            popup("Warning", "Wrong format for a float number !", elem=window[key])

window.close()
```

There will be still problem if you switch to other program, it will still generate `FocusOut` event when focus is in any binding input. It maybe better to valid all inputs after one button `submit` clicked.

Comment: Thank you again Jason Yang. I tried it and it works for fields that have numbers (floats) in them but of course 'bombs out' on a field like the date, as you said it would. Interestingly I wrote the same program in Tkinter and there I don't have these problems. If no value is entered a popup asks 'Did you put in fuel?' If 'Yes' Focus is returned otherwise it continues. Perhaps I must try something like that?

Comment: I just checked my Tkinter program and noticed that the IN4 date also has a default value so that one cannot have a blank field. I will work on that. I like the way that you modified the code to immediately format the input. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I got the same issue if I switch from one input to another input and both of them binded with event `'<FocusOut>'`

Comment: Yip, putting a default date (today) in IN4 prevents having no date so that's the way I'll go. Thanks for all your help. I have learnt a lot.